# CSS - positioning navigation title

Tags: html, css, navigation, positioning

I was wondering how can I position navigation titles so that my dropdown menu would work..
The following picture is my perfectly positioned a links, separated thanks to padding-left, which is set to 80 px; Strangely enough, my dropdown category is padded as well, leaving extra space, which makes it very ugly to look. And my dropdown menu link is separated in two lines, although it is only one link. How can I fix this problem? I tried with margin as well, nothing really changed. I would like it to be something like this the third picture..

Picture one - My desired navigation positioning :

http://i61.tinypic.com/2cshw7q.png

Picture two - My dropdown problem :

http://i60.tinypic.com/2z4037c.png

Picture three - The way I would like it to be:

http://i60.tinypic.com/1252ejo.png

How can I accomplish this?

EDIT!

My CSS code:

```
#menu 
{
clear:both;
position: relative;
width: 100%;
height:30px;
background: rgb(38,42,53); /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(38,42,53,1) 0%, rgba(40,45,63,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(38,42,53,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(40,45,63,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(38,42,53,1) 0%,rgba(40,45,63,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(38,42,53,1) 0%,rgba(40,45,63,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(38,42,53,1) 0%,rgba(40,45,63,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(38,42,53,1) 0%,rgba(40,45,63,1) 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#262a35', endColorstr='#282d3f',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}

ul#menu {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 15px;
}


    ul#menu li{
    position: relative; 
    display:inline-block;
    /*float:left;*/
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    }


ul#menu li a{
display:block;
float:left;
color:#84FD00;                /* #874B46 */
text-decoration:none;
padding-left: 80px;
padding-top: 5px;
}

ul#menu li ul {
    margin-top:20px;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow:none;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: 0;
    padding-left: 30px;
}

ul#menu li ul li {
    background: rgb(38,42,53); /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(38,42,53,1) 0%, rgba(40,45,63,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(38,42,53,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(40,45,63,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(38,42,53,1) 0%,rgba(40,45,63,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(38,42,53,1) 0%,rgba(40,45,63,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(38,42,53,1) 0%,rgba(40,45,63,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(38,42,53,1) 0%,rgba(40,45,63,1) 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#262a35', endColorstr='#282d3f',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    color: #8BA8C5;
    height: 40px;
    }

ul#menu li  ul li:hover { 

    background: #666; 

    }

ul#menu li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    margin-right:20px;
    }
```

Comment: ....code? HTML, CSS, jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Please provide a code example

Comment: I added the CSS code.

Answer (score 0):

Set the dropdown ul to have `text-align: left;` - this should show the text on the left hand side. For some reason your text is right aligned...

Comment: try the ul li or ul li a to have the text-align. You could even try adding `!important` to the end of the text-align style.